# Wrapping a number?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have this float which is a rotation angle.

```
Camera.roty += (float) diffx * 0.2;
```

where diff is the change in mouse position.

In OpenGL it will wrap it if it exceeds 360 or is below 0, but how could I do this if I want to verify if the angle is between 0 and 180?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a little bit what you mean by "wrapping"?

Comment: @Thomasz- I think he means that an angle of 365 would get automatically converted to 5 (or -90 would get converted to 270).  Essentially, `angle % 360`.

Comment: Which angle do you want to verify? `diffx`?  `Camera.roty` before the addition happens? After the addition?

Comment: but % only acceps integers, not floats

Comment: after the addition, camera.rotx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with floating-point values, you could do:

```
angle = angle - floor(angle / 360) * 360;
```

This should deal with negative values properly too (-1 would be converted to 359).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you're basically looking for something like this?:

```
float Wrap( const float Number, const float Max, const float Min ) {
 if( Number > 0.0f ) {
  return fmod( Number, Max ) + Min;
 }
 else {
  return Max - fmod( abs( Number ), Max ) + Min;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to comment by @bta:

why not use:

```
angle % 180
```

and save that number as an angle?

Comment: you could save information about the sign, abs() it, and then mod, at the end multiplying by sign.